# Want to change the Tab on Button Click using Tabbed activity

Tags: android

I want to change the tab from Person_Info to Morphology on the click of NEXT button.

I am handling the button click in the respective fragment class i.e. in PersonInfo class something like in the code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pass the button click event to your activity from your fragment, where the you will have view pager available and simply select the next tab.

```
public class YourFragment {
    YourNextTabListener  listener;
// .. initializations 

// on next button click listener
     onClick(View v) {
        listener.onNextTabButtonClick();
     }


public interface YourNextTabListener {
   void onNextTabButtonClick();
   void onPreviousTabButtonClick();
}

}
```

In your Activity which contains fragment implement `YourNextTabListener`

```
public class YourActivity implements YourNextTabListener {

    Tablayout tablayout;

    @override
    void onCreate () {
        //tablayout initialize
    }

    //.
    //.
    //.
    @override 
    void onNextTabButtonClick(){
        // tablayout.setCurrentTab(<next_tab_index>)
    }
    @override
    void onPreviousTabButtonClick(){

       }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you are saying..? What should I do in onNextTabButtonClick()..?

Comment: OK.. I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
int index=2;
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(index);
tab.select();//may produce null pointer exception if index not found.
```

Answer (score -1):

Already try this?:

```
//Activity.java
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
Button next = findViewById(R.id.button);
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
             viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        }
    });
});

//Fragment.java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View _view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);

    Button next = _view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
             viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
           } 
       });
   });
   return _view;
}
```

Comment: What causes crashes? do you correctly assign  id for pager and button?

Comment: I am doing this in fragment class but the viewpager is present in Main Xml file. In this case how should I do this..?

Comment: I used fragment too, but above code can still be used in activity.java onCreate with no crashes in my case.

Comment: try adding : viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); before setAdapter

Comment: the button is not available in Activity but its inside the fragment, so this will crash.

Comment: What I understand with your help that you are saying to write this code in main activity, but I am handling the click event in the respective fragment class, so in fragment class it is not working properly...

Comment: Suggest me that If I made the Main activity a singleton class ? does it works..?

Comment: @UmarHussain exactly that's what I asking.. ?

Comment: No need to make a singleton class, that not how android works. You have to pass the event from fragment to your activity using interfaces as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: By the way! Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Already edited the answer, you can try if other answer not work out for you

Comment: where you have defined the viewpager in fragment class..?

Comment: It's changing the tab now but can't displaying the contents of second fragment..?

Comment: Are you already added setOffscreenPageLimit ? or still doesn't have Viewpager?